# Error while opening .xls file from asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code when I wanted to export to excel the data from my datagrid. 
The data comes from SQL. I'm using ASP.NET C#.

```
 protected void ExportToExcel()
    {
        GridView gv = new GridView();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Serials.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        dt = new DataTable();
        dt = RetrieveResultsTable();
        //gv.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = Color. #CCFFFF
        gv.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(204, 255, 255);
        gv.DataSource = dt;
        gv.DataBind();
        gv.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        Response.End();
    }
```

When I export it, it yields an warning/error:

[image: Different format than the specified extension]

And though I have searched solutions by modifying the registry by

[image: registry modification]

I dont want to modify the registry since this would be very much hassle, configuring every browser users.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: It doesn't look like you're actually saving it as an Excel *format*, only that you give it an .xls extension. What am I missing here?

Comment: xls is legacy excel, older versions of excel.  Use xlsx instead.  In short rename the file to xlsx at their sources.  Might work.

Comment: I have already tried that @Ryios, but still the same warning/error. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen could there be other options aside from 3rd party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

`gv.RenderControl(htw)`

You are just sending an HTML text file to the client's browser disguised as an XLS file, of course Excel will complain.

As pointed by Lasse, files don't magically change their format by just specifying an extension. Look into available libraries, e.g. [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/), for a proper way to create Excel format files out of any tabular data.

Also, you should send the file to the browser from an ASHX generic handler which bypasses most of the ASP.NET page life-cycle stuff so you won't have to deal with any queued output in your response.

Comment: Could there be other solutions that doesn't involve any open source libraries?

Comment: @Juran, if you have Excel installed on the server, you can do interop without using third party libraries.

Comment: excel is already installed on the server but this still happens

Comment: I said you can do _[interop](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel)_ if it's installed. What you're doing will _never_ succeed.